# JWPlayer Interactive Transcript

Tags: jwplayer6, interactive-transcript

I am having difficulty implementing JWPlayer's interactive transcript as shown here:
http://demo.jwplayer.com/iframes/interactive-transcript/
A search shows I am not alone. A tutorial on this would be most helpful.

I have tried several variations using the source code. It seems the transcript is generated on the fly from the captions.vtt file. Is this correct? I can not locate or don't have access to this file on JW's server.

In my local install(MAMP) on lines 133, 168, & 191 of the source code I have replaced the path with one to a local file but to no avail.
I tried using the "generated" source code which includes the created transcript but the interactivity actions still fail.

Any help would be appreciated.